# Dividing an integer variable is not working

Tags: swift, variables, integer, rounding

I have an integer variable that I'm dividing by 100 and then storing in a string variable.  That string variable is then put in label text:

```
var paymentMultiplyR: Int!
var paymentMathTotalConvertR: String = ""

// Take integer 'paymentMultiplyR' divide by 100 and convert to String for label text
   paymentMathTotalConvertR = toString(paymentMultiplyR/100)

// Load payment amount into labels
   self.redPaymentO.text = "= \(paymentMathTotalConvertR) cents"
```

The output is "3 cents" in the label text when I run the app.  When doing on a calculator it is 3.5 and I need it to ultimately be 3.50  in the label text.  How do I do this?  I've looked into:

```
round(variable * 100) / 100
```

But I can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing `Int` types always returns `Int` types.  Try:

```
round(variable * 100) / 100.0
```

It's not clear what `variable` is, if it's not a double, do this:

```
round(Double(variable) * 100) / 100.0
```

Comment: Dividing by a decimal point and not just 100 fixed my problem when trying to convert a number to a decimal point thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you divide an `Int` by an `Int`, the result is another `Int`. That is, any remainder is truncated. So 350/100 will give you 3, not 3.5.

Convert your values to `Double` or `Float` before dividing:

```
Double(350) / Double(100)
```

Comment: In the example I gave, how would I convert to a double or a float?  I'm new to programming, sorry.